# Why do we need a Unique key when we have a Primary key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, rdbms

I tried to Google this question but all I found were differences between primary and unique keys, why do we actually need a unique key when we have a primary key that can identify any single record, could someone provide an example to explain this or maybe provide a link that explains this.

Comment: Also worth mentioning (from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)): `If a table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB generates a hidden clustered index named GEN_CLUST_INDEX on a synthetic column that contains row ID values. The rows are ordered by the row ID that InnoDB assigns. The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in order of insertion.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do we actually need a unique key when we have a primary key?

Short answer -- You don't.

Long answer:

In MySQL, the `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.

There is only one `PRIMARY KEY`; its main function is to uniquely identify each row.

A `UNIQUE` key is allowed to contain a column that is `NULLable`.

`UNIQUE` is a uniqueness constraint and an Index.

Any flavor of an index may include multiple columns; the order of the columns in the definition matters.  (The order of conditions in a `WHERE` clause does not matter.)

A `FOREIGN KEY` is a `CONSTRAINT` and it implicitly creates an `INDEX` if there is not already one that works for the constraint.

Each of these pairs is redundant; Drop the second:

```
PRIMARY KEY (a)
UNIQUE (a)

INDEX(c,d)
INDEX(c)

UNIQUE(e)
UNIQUE(e,f)

UNIQUE(h)
UNIQUE(g,h)  -- or consider making changing to INDEX(g,h)
```

If you build a table without a `PRIMARY KEY` but with a `UNIQUE` key, consider changing "unique" to "primary key".

It is very rare for a table to need 3 `UNIQUE` keys (including the PK); rethink the schema.

Some programmers always have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` (usually named `id`) as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  But this is not always necessary, and it *sometimes* interferes with performance.

Caveat:  Some of the above statements may not apply to RDBMSs other than MySQL and MariaDB.

Caveat:  Index-prefixing, Partitioning, and a few other obscure things are not covered above.

Two common cases for a PK + a UNIQUE:

- Lookup table (for 'normalizing'):  The table has an `id` (auto_increment, PK) and a string (Unique).
- Many-to-mapping table: Two columns, each being an `id` into some other table.  The PK would be the pair of columns in some order; the `UNIQUE` would be the pair in the other order.  (Technically, a plain `INDEX` suffices for that second index.)

Comment: As every table has to have a primary key, what is the purpose of unique key at all, it could just be similar to any other column

Comment: @SwayamShah - I added the two main examples of needing two Unique indexes.